# AWS SNS / SMS: Accented characters look garbled on the phone

Tags: character-encoding, amazon-sns

I'm sending a message containing accents like so:

`sns.publish({ Message: 'Olá, Jean', PhoneNumber: '+55...' })`

But it gets rendered `Ol?ean`. How can I fix this?

- Platform: NodeJS.
- aws-sdk version: 2.6.9.
- SNS API version: 2010-03-31.

Comment: Have you found how to solve it ? Getting the same here. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @GIJOW. I've worked around it by using the diacritics npm module to remove all accents and that was it. I've noticed some services, such as Twilio, promise to do their best to encode messages appropriately, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: So you send messages without accents ?

Comment: Yeap. Figured it's better than broken accents... :( Also been having delays and deliverability problems using Amazon SNS to send messages to Brazilian phone numbers; on the look for better alternatives.

Comment: Yes, facing similar issues here even for others countries. Thank you for your feedback