# AWS SNS SMS with special characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, special-characters, amazon-sns

I'm sending SMSs through AWS Simple Notification Service (SNS), and it all seems to work just fine, except when I try to send messages with special characters, tilded characters to be specific (they are in Spanish).

For instance, if I send something like: `Tu código de verificación es: 1234`, I receive the message like this:

```
@T@u @c@?@?@d@i@g@o@ @d@e@ @v@e@r@i@f@i@c@a@c@i@?@?@n@ @e@s@:@ @1@2@3@4@"
```

With a bunch of @s.

If I remove the tilded Os, i.e., send the message like this: `Tu codigo de verificacion es: 1234`, I receive it exactly like that.

I've tried utf8 encoding the message string without any success. I can't find anything on the AWS SNS documentation... or anywhere else, to be honest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to send this message from sns to email or mobile?

Comment: SMS. It says right at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html), the published message must be UTF-8 encoded. You didn't specify how the SMS is published.

Have you tried to send the message via the console, to double check if it is working at all?

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html) AWS page also provides code examples on the bottom for every programming language that should work and do UTF-8.

In the end you might be out of luck, as the SMS encoding seems to be a mess. See an explanation from another SMS provider [here](https://help.goacoustic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043843154--How-character-encoding-affects-SMS-message-length), where they state that many phones, networks, and mobile providers don't support UTF-8, but UTF-16/UCS-2 (AWS doesn't support UTF-16). An older [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848486/aws-sns-sms-accented-characters-look-garbled-on-the-phone) question has had the same issue and they replaced the characters in the end.

Comment: Hi. According to the first link you shared, "With the exception of SMS, messages must be UTF-8 encoded strings...".

I'm using a (PHP) SDK, and, like I said, the SMS arrives, but with a bunch of @ characters in between each character of my message. So it wouldn't really help sending it via the console... I did it anyways, and got the exact same result

Comment: What exact same result did you get when sending it via console? The @@ in the messages? If that is so, then there might be an issue with AWS -> Mobile Carrier or a bug in AWS itself. You should contact AWS support and see if they can help you.

Sending via console was necessary for debbuging if there is something wrong between your code -> AWS or AWS -> mobile carrier.

Comment: I have tried to send messages using console to email as well as sms. There is no problem at all. You need to check your encoding in your code so there is no problem from aws side. @augunrik is right

Comment: If not you can also explore aws pinpoint service as it has supported character sets

Comment: Yeah. That could be an alternative. Thanks !